# Upload report to RPubs from Terminal or on website?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

Can I publish an R markdown report from either within the R shell (in Terminal) or somehow "upload" it when I'm on the RPubs website?

Or can I only do this from within the RStudio IDE?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `publish_rpubs` function from the [slidify](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify) library. First install slidify using the [devtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/index.html) package:

```
 devtools::install_github('slidify', 'ramnathv')
 devtools::install_github('slidifyLibraries', 'ramnathv')
```

Then to publish to rpubs:

```
 slidify::publish_rpubs("name of document", "document.html")
```

You will then be prompted to sign in your web browser and provide document details